# How do I set the default for terminal/console size in CentOS 7 to larger than 80x25?

Tags: centos7

I just created a new VirtualBox VM of CentOS 7

When I start the VM, the terminal is in 80x25.

I see ALOT of results from searches about changing grub settings, but none work and all are for either older versions of CentOS or other ditros like Ubuntu (but like I said, they don't work)

Yes, I can get the terminal size I want if I SSH to the VM, but I want the console to be larger.

Comment: What have your tried so far (the content of those search results), just so we're not suggesting things you've already tried.

Comment: I edited /etc/default/grub and rebuilt (but what should I put there?) no change to terminal size